# Axios get method is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am just calling the api get using reactJS and axios.
The api call is going but I'm unable to get the response from the server.

Here is my code:

```
getProjectdetails(details) {
  alert("coming")
  details.map(function(project, i) {
    var projectId = project.projectId
    axios.get('http://workpresso.rankworld.io/api/v1/project?query={"projectId":"' + projectId + '"}', {
        params: {},
        headers: {
          "x-access-token": sessionStorage.token
        },
      })
      .then(function(response1) {}.bind(this))
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to return something from the then().
If you want to avoid binding 'this' you can use an arrow function (if es6 is available, assuming you're using Node, it probably is).
Lastly, a map function transforms the array elements, so you need to return something in that function too.